# will_paginate and nested routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

How do I paginate activities for a given project
In my routes file I have

```
resources :projects do 
 resources :activities
end
```

In my activities controller (should it go in my Projects controller?)

```
def index
@project = current_user.projects.find(params[:project_id])
@activities = @project.activities.all.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @activities }
end
end
```

In my view

```
<%= will_paginate @project.activities %>
```

However no error returned but pagination is missing under table. Any idea?

Comment: If an answer helped you, please don't forget to mark it as correct =)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I would urge you to check out Kaminari for your pagination plugin as will_paginate seemed to have stalled out and its still only in pre-release 2 for Rails 3.

https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

Secondly, in your view try doing:

```
<%= will_paginate @activities %>
```

You're not linking to the variable @activities you created in your controller.